# Improve Intellij Code Inspection for may produce NullPointerException warnings

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, code-inspection

I have a class with a `hasField` function that checks if a field is present and not null, and a `getField` function that returns the value of the field (or null if not present).

In my code when I call `getField` right after checking `hasField`, I know that getField is not going to return null, but the IDE Inspection (*Constant Conditions and Exceptions*) doesn't know that. I get a bunch of method `method name` may produce a `NullPointerException`

I'm trying to find a clean way to make this warning go away.

**Workarounds**

Here are some workarounds I could do but I find all of these hacky:

1. Surround `getField` with `Objects.requireNotnull`, the code would be no-op. Would prefer not doing that as it makes the code slightly less readable.
2. Suppress warnings where I know this is safe. Again not preferred as this is going to happen at a bunch of places in our code.
3. Ignore warnings. In this case we might miss legit warnings just because warnings section will be too noisy.

**Ideal solution**

Would I be able to somehow set up the warnings in such a way that if `hasField` is true, then `getField` will return a non-null? I looked into [JetBrains Contract Annotations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/contract-annotations.html) but doing what I want here seems to be beyond what is supported with @Contract

**Code Sample**

Here's a minimum working code sample that demonstrates the issue:

```
import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class Hello {

  private Hello(){}
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestClass test1 = new TestClass(null);
    if (test1.hasSample()) {
      System.out.println(test1.getSample().equals("abc"));
    }
 }
}

class TestClass {
  private final String sample;

  TestClass(String field) { this.sample = field; }

  boolean hasSample() { return sample != null; }

  @Nullable public String getSample() { return sample; }
}
```

I get the following warning

> Method invocation `equals` may produce `NullPointerException`

I'd ideally want to be able to tell IDE that getSample is not null when hasSample is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclosure* I'm IntelliJ IDEA developer responsible for this subsystem

---

No, it's not possible now. There's no better solution than possible workarounds you already listed, assuming that you cannot change the API. The closest thing we have is the inlining of very trivial methods. However, it works only if:

- The methods like `hasSample()` and `getSample()` are called from the same class
- The called methods cannot be overridden (private/static/final/declared in final class)

E.g. this feature works in the following code:

```java
final class TestClass { // if final is removed, the warning will appear again
  private final String sample;

  TestClass(String field) { this.sample = field; }

  boolean hasSample() { return sample != null; }

  @Nullable
  public String getSample() { return sample; }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    if (hasSample()) {
      return "TestClass: "+getSample().trim(); // no warning on trim() invocation here
    }
    return "TestClass";
  }
}
```

For now, I can only suggest refactoring your APIs to Optionals like this:

```java
import java.util.Optional;

public class Hello {

  private Hello(){}
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestClass test1 = new TestClass(null);
    test1.getSample().ifPresent(s -> System.out.println(s.equals("abc")));
    // or fancier: test1.getSample().map("abc"::equals).ifPresent(System.out::println);
  }
}

final class TestClass {
  private final String sample;

  TestClass(String field) { this.sample = field; }

  public Optional<String> getSample() { return Optional.ofNullable(sample); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. For now I've decided to just ignore the warnings.